# Slider Drawer taking up entire screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, menu, slider

I've created a custom sliding menu, but it seems to take up all of the screen. By that I mean that I cannot click on other items on the layout. It is not always open, it just practically disables all the items 'under' it. I've attached my xml for one activity

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description1"
        android:src="@drawable/fam" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/enter" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#666"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#333"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:paddingRight="15sp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Change its height `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of match_parent:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Also, post a screenshot to your question.

Comment: Nope, now it wont even start, Logcat is giving me a `E/AndroidRuntime(1275): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.`

Answer (score 0):

Please change the width

```
   <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"//not indp
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#666"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#333"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:paddingRight="15sp"
        />
```

and drawer should be parent of all view please try this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description1"
        android:src="@drawable/fam" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/enter" />
</RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"//not indp
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#666"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#333"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:paddingRight="15sp"
        />
```

Comment: Changed the width, it still works the same as before. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `android:layout_below="@+id/button1"`  to your `DrawerLayout` as below:

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"> //set your drawer layout at the bottom of your `Button`.
```

Answer (score 0):

please check training article on Android Developers regarding DrawerLayout - http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#top

It seems you use it not right way, from my point of view. As is written in article above: **the following layout uses a DrawerLayout with two child views: a FrameLayout to contain the main content (populated by a Fragment at runtime), and a ListView for the navigation drawer.**

This frame layout is used for your Activity content. So you must use fragments

> ```
> <FrameLayout
>         android:id="@+id/content_frame"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
> ```

And this ListView is content of Navigation Drawer

> ```
> <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
>         android:layout_width="240dp"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_gravity="start"
>         android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
>         android:divider="#666"
>         android:dividerHeight="1dp"
>         android:background="#333"
>         android:paddingLeft="15sp"
>         android:paddingRight="15sp"
>         />
> ```

So put other your components into fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and the code below worked for me. Use it instead of match parent:
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
```

I had this feature to my code. I put android:layout_height="wrap_content"  and i deleted marginTop and i had full height SlidingDrawer.